# how to save chat transcripts in sql server database and retrieve it on another page with formatting?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, sql-server

I am Working on a chat application in which i used a multiline textbox to show messages. Now First of all i want to give different colors in my chat. Our user message should be in different color and another user message should be in different color. 
Second thing i want that i want to save transcripts of chat conversation with formatting so that user can see it anytime. 
I don't know how to save transcript to database with formatting. So i am stucked here.
I am using C# and Sql server database.
How can i do that?

Comment: Please show some effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break down your problem, then it would make it much easier to solve it.

1. Instead of taking text from textbox. Have you thought about maybe storing it as xml?
2. If you use xml, you can use xslt to generate a nice looking html (but it depends on how you want to use it later)
3. You have different options how you store it in the database

   - plain text
   - xml
   - blob

Please do your research and then ask specific questions if you get stuck.